# Select Unique Posts for a List of Tags

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I have a query returning a list of tags based on my search criteria. I am looking for a way to return a list of posts for these tags however I would like to exclude redundant posts from the results.

for instance tag list is A, B, C, D. I want a total of 4 posts. If the most recent post for A is also tagged B I would like a different result for tag B and so on.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with something more efficient than four queries using an accumulating "not in" list :-s

Comment: In fact it's harder too - you don't want choices for the first few tags to run you out of options for later tags, do you?

Comment: My hopes are I wouldn't be run out of posts, but I guess my next best option would be to drop that tag and use the next one. Are you feeling a separate query for each tag appending the post id to a "not in" statement is my best option? That's really where I am, but trying to save on making so many queries.

Comment: Yeh. I can't convince myself that anything else is possible. If it were me I'd make an editor (as in a human) choose a featured post per category instead.

Comment: thanks @AndyMacaulay-Brook but Im looking for a way to show popular tags, not featured tags

Comment: Yeh I get that. I mean the posts could be manually selected. So your code can work out the most popular tag but the post it shows could just be the post assigned to that tag for that purpose.